# Geometric Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading Milne's note on etale cohomology, he mentions about geometric point.I know the definition for schemes but I am confused about what does it mean for varieties. So any help like equivalent formulations will be helpful.

Comment: A variety is a scheme, so the same definition applies.

Comment: So it is just a morphism from spec(k)

Answer (score 2):

To get this off the unaswered list. A geometric point of a scheme/variety $X$ is a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to X$ where $k$ is separably closed.